# "allure to your sense of decency"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

> I'm trying to **allure** to your sense of decency

Does the above sentence make sense? Can the word allure be used in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is *appeal*, not *allure*.

I suspect you have used a dictionary or thesaurus in which *allure* and *appeal* are given as "synonyms".

But the overlap between these two terms is very small. The core sense of *allure* is to *attract powerfully*—usually to tempt someone to do something prohibited or dangerous. The core sense of *appeal* is  to *make an earnest request*, particularly to petition an authority for some benefit or relief.

Consequently, it is almost cliched to "appeal to your sense of decency" (or to your sense of honour or justice, or your better nature) when entreating someone to refrain from an undesirable action.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. I think you are looking for [***allude***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/allude):

> to refer in a casual or indirect way (to)

Comment: Allude sounds wrong too.

Comment: Maybe, but it is hard to tell without any context. I was considering a similar sounding word that may have been mistaken.

Comment: No, I can't think of any context allude would work in the OPs situation. Were you thinking of Appeal, as in the other answer?